# Postgresql-Server won't start after moving data directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

I am running a local postgresql server (9.5 & 9.6) on my Ubuntu 17.04 machine. After moving my data directories to another hard drive following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04) the server can't start.

I.e. with

```
sudo service postgresql restart && sudo service postgresql status 

● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-11-06 10:31:32 CET; 1min 42s ago
  Process: 8962 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8962 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 06 10:31:32 HERCULES systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Nov 06 10:31:32 HERCULES systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

The logs for both versions then contain the following:

```
pg_ctl: could not access directory "/media/daveknave/BIGFS/PGSQL/9.5/main": Keine Berechtigung
```

"Keine Berechtigung" translates to "Permission denied".

```
ls -l /media/daveknave/BIGFS/PGSQL/9.5/main
```

gives

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 base
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov  3 21:07 global
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_clog
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_commit_ts
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_dynshmem
drwxrwxrwx 4 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_logical
drwxrwxrwx 4 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_multixact
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov  3 21:07 pg_notify
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_replslot
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_serial
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_snapshots
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov  3 21:07 pg_stat
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_stat_tmp
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_subtrans
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_tblspc
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 25 21:42 pg_twophase
-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres    4 Sep 25 21:42 PG_VERSION
drwxrwxrwx 3 postgres postgres 4096 Nov  2 10:19 pg_xlog
-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres   88 Sep 25 21:42 postgresql.auto.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres  133 Nov  3 21:07 postmaster.opts
-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres  100 Nov  3 21:07 postmaster.pid
```

I've set the file permissions in an attempt to solve this, however no result.

Trying to access the server using

```
sudo -u postgres psql -W
```

prompts

```
Password: 
psql: could not connect to server: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Can anybody please help? Have any of you encountered that same issue? I've searched using google, but couldn't find any hints to solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verify the permissions on `/main` with

```
ls -l /media/daveknave/BIGFS/PGSQL/9.5/
```

Does `postgres` still have access to `main`?

Switch user to `postgres` with `su - postgres` and then navigate through the directory structure `/media/daveknave/BIGFS/PGSQL/9.5/main/`. Can you navigate past `main` into `base`?

Verify the file permissions beneath `..../base` with the following comamnds:

```
ls -lR /media/daveknave/BIGFS/PGSQL/9.5/main/base > ~/postrgres_main_perm.log
```

and then

```
vi ~/postrgres_main_perm.log
```

If you find that the permissions are not correct in the log file, then run the following command to grant `postgres` all permissions to the directory `...main/base` and all underlying sub-directories:

```
chown -Rv postgres:postgres /media/daveknave/BIGFS/PGSQL/9.5/main/base/
```

> **Caution:**
>   Before you modify all permissions ensure the command works by replacing `chown -Rv` with something less destructive like `ls -R` or navigate down to the `.../main` directory and issue the shorter command: `chown -Rv postgres:postgres base/`. This will ensure you are applying the command to the correct directory.

Try restarting your PostgreSQL instance again.

Comment: Great! Thanks to your answer I was able to find out the kind of obvious. The issue was that postgres did not have permissions to access _/media/daveknave_ and _BIGFS_ underneath. I chowned. **Important: Files and directories must have u=rwx (0700) permissions.**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but because a very strange reason... In my opinion...

See these outputs...

```
root@srv_nm:/tmp# chown -R postgres "/some/path/data"
root@srv_nm:/tmp# chown -R :postgres "/some/path/data"
root@srv_nm:/tmp# chmod -R 700 "/some/path/data"
root@srv_nm:/tmp# ls -al "/some/path/data"
total 40
drws--S--- 15 postgres postgres   293 Mar 23 13:19 .
drwxrwxrwx  3 postgres postgres    46 Mar 23 14:57 ..
drws--S---  9 postgres postgres    97 Sep 28  2017 base
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres  4096 Mar 11 14:39 global
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb 15 13:53 pg_clog
drws--S---  4 postgres postgres    36 Sep 27  2017 pg_multixact
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres    18 Mar 11 14:39 pg_notify
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_serial
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_snapshots
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres   105 Mar 12 20:23 pg_stat
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Mar 12 20:23 pg_stat_tmp
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres    18 Mar 12 18:27 pg_subtrans
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_tblspc
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_twophase
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres     4 Sep 27  2017 PG_VERSION
drws--S---  3 postgres postgres   284 Mar 12 20:22 pg_xlog
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres 20644 Mar 23 12:59 postgresql.conf
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres   131 Mar 11 14:39 postmaster.opts
root@srv_nm:/tmp# sudo -u postgres ls -al /some/path/data
ls: cannot access '/some/path/data': Permission denied
```

See the last command...

```
root@srv_nm:/tmp# sudo -u postgres ls -al /some/path/data
ls: cannot access '/some/path/data': Permission denied
```

But, if I do this...

```
root@srv_nm:/tmp# mv "/some/path/data" "/some/"
```

Voilà...

```
root@srv_nm:/tmp# sudo -u postgres ls -al "/some/data"
total 40
drws--S--- 15 postgres postgres   293 Mar 23 13:19 .
drwx------  7 postgres postgres    90 Mar 23 15:12 ..
drws--S---  9 postgres postgres    97 Sep 28  2017 base
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres  4096 Mar 11 14:39 global
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb 15 13:53 pg_clog
drws--S---  4 postgres postgres    36 Sep 27  2017 pg_multixact
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres    18 Mar 11 14:39 pg_notify
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_serial
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_snapshots
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres   105 Mar 12 20:23 pg_stat
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Mar 12 20:23 pg_stat_tmp
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres    18 Mar 12 18:27 pg_subtrans
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_tblspc
drws--S---  2 postgres postgres     6 Sep 27  2017 pg_twophase
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres     4 Sep 27  2017 PG_VERSION
drws--S---  3 postgres postgres   284 Mar 12 20:22 pg_xlog
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres 20644 Mar 23 12:59 postgresql.conf
-rwx------  1 postgres postgres   131 Mar 11 14:39 postmaster.opts
```

**FURTHER QUESTION:**

I just can't understand why this access problem occurs in relation to the path... If anyone has an explanation for that, it would be great!

**Thanks! =D**

Comment: postgres probably isn't the owner of `/some/path/` and isn't allowed to get inside. So the correct permissions below that are never reached. I had a similar problem and `chmod ugo+rX /some/path` fixed it.

Comment: I have the same issue with PostgreSQL14 and ubuntu 22.04, but none of the solutions listed here worked. Access is granted, ownership is appropriate, but still access denied.